# Show that the sequence $(T_n)_{n\geq 1}$ converges in probability to the constant $2p$

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Let $X_n$ ~ Bernoulli(p). Let $Y_n = X_n + X_{n+1}$. 
Let $T_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i$. 
I want to show that the sequence $(T_n)_{n\geq 1}$ converges in probability to the constant 2p.

I found that $E[T_n] = 2p$ and that $\operatorname{Var}[T_n] = 2p(1-p)\frac{2n-1}{n^2}$.

My definition of convergence in probability is the following: 
$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \space\mathbb{P}(\vert T_n - 2p \vert > \epsilon) \to 0$$

I can also use the following criterion:

Convergence in probability iff $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}\Big[\frac{\vert T_n - 2p\vert}{\vert T_n - 2p\vert + 1}\Big] = 0$$

To me using the criterion here seems smart because I already know that the expected value is $2p$, but I am not sure how to proceed. Any hints?

Comment: Hint: You can try to use Chebyshev's inequality $\mathbb{P}\bigl(|X-EX|>\epsilon\bigr)\leq \frac{Var(X)}{\epsilon^2}.$

Comment: Can you use the law of large numbers?

Comment: @dem0nakos I didn't know that inequality, super useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Claim.* If $\mu_n = \mathbf{E}(T_n) \to \mu$ and $\sigma_n^2 = \mathbf{V}\mathrm{ar}(T_n) \to 0$ then $T_n \to \mu$ in $\mathscr{L}^2$ and, hence, in probability too.

*Proof.* We have $\mathbf{E}(|T_n - \mu|^2) = \mathbf{E}(|T_n - \mu_n|^2) + 2(\mu_n - \mu) \mathbf{E}(T_n - \mu_n) + (\mu_n - \mu)^2 \to 0.$ Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$
T_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i + X_{i+1}) = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \frac{1}{n}X_1
$$

Now $X_n$ is an i.i.d sequence of random variables with mean $E(X_i)=p$, thus the law of large numbers states that

$$
2 \cdot \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \overset{P}{\to} 2 p
$$

and since $X_1$ is constant, clearly $\frac{1}{n} X_1 \overset{P}{\to} 0$ thus yielding

$$
T_n \overset{P}{\to} 2 p
$$

as desired.