# Exercise 6.18 from Probability Path (Resnick)

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I'm trying to solve an exercise from Resnick's book and I'm convinced there is an assumption missing. The following is the exercise's content:

[image]

My attempt was to use the definition directly

$$ \mathbb{E} \left[\left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n^\alpha}\right)^2\right]  =
\frac{\mathbb{E}^2\left( \sum_i^nX_i \right) + \text{Var} \left( \sum_i^nX_i \right)}{n^{2\alpha}},$$

the second term is $\leq nc$ so it's limit is 0 when divided by $n^{2\alpha}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, but I can't figure out why the first terms also needs to go to 0.

As a counter example: If $\mathbb{P}(X_n = e^n) = 1$, then all the assumptions made are valid, but the result is not true. I think even limiting $\mathbb{E}(X_i)$ would not be enough.

Is there an error on the exercise (assumption like $\mathbb{E}(X_i) = 0$ missing) or there is something wrong with my solution attempt?

Comment: I tried two or three things to fix it, and it is probably just flawed. However, if you define $$K_n = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \dfrac{X_n}{n^\alpha}$$ and assume $\mathbf{E}(K_n) \to \mu$ for some constant $\mu$ and $\mathbf{V}\mathrm{ar}(X_n)$ to be uniformly bounded, then $K_n \to \mu$ in $\mathscr{L}^2.$ As it follows easily from my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3062073/show-that-the-sequence-t-n-n-geq-1-converges-in-probability-to-the-constan/3062085#3062085